# ipatool failed with an exception: #<CmdSpec::NonZeroExcitException: Command exited with pid 29483 exit 1:

Tags: objective-c, xcode10, xcode10.1

[image]

ipatool failed with an exception: #

Stderr:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Xcode10.1，Objective-C

Comment: Looks like an issue in the alipay SDK.  Post your question [here](https://github.com/alipay/alipay-sdk-python-all/issues).